# Como remover a seta de expansão de texto caso não tenha necessidade

Tags: javascript

Quero remover as setas (apontada para baixo) dos posts que não tenha necessidade de expansão (já que não tem muito texto para ser mostrado) e deixar essa seta nos posts que tem muito mais texto, para que quando seja clicado revele.

EX: o primeiro post só tem uma linha, então quero remover a seta dele! 
já o segundo post tem muitas outras linhas a ser mostradas então quero esse post  continue com a seta!

Remover um elemento eu sei, só não sei como eu vou saber se a quantidade de texto já ultrapassou o limite que está sendo mostrado.

Eu tinha feito um post antes desse, e a ideia era verificar a altura do pai e do filho (que está com o texto) se a do filho for maior que a do pai então mostra seta se não não remova.
Mas o problema e que meu div filho tem tamanho fixo e não posso alterar a estrutura, isso significa que o filho nunca vai ultrapassar a div pai, isso significa que esse método não funciona!
Alguem sabe mais um jeito?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Para vc conseguir um exito maior na resposta, procure postar o código que vc já fez, aí o pessoal vai ver a melhor forma de lhe auxiliar.

Comment: O método do span deveria funcionar, mesmo o elemento filho sendo fixo, o span com o texto não seria.

Comment: faça um cálculo da quantidade de caracteres necessários para não exibir as setas, dessa forma você pode utilizar javascript ou jquery para analisar caso a quantidade seja maior do que x ele exibe as setas

Comment: melhor contar a quantidade de linhas  entao coloca o botao se for menor que 4 entao nao coloca! como posso contar as linhas??
contar usando \n porque por mais que eu nao use o \n a linha quebra quando chega no final e continua em baixo entao contar linihas de uma div usando \n da erro! alguem sabe fazer isso?

Comment: cole seus códigos para analisarmos e ajudá-lo melhor